# RegEx for client-side server in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, regex-group, client-side-validation

I'm doing server-side and client-side validation for names in my rails application. Currently, I have to duplicate the regular expression because the constant that works on the server is throwing an error. How can I modify the code so I don't have this duplication?

#### app/models/resident.rb

```
  NAME_FORMAT = /^(?!.*\.\S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ \',.-]+$/

  validate :name_is_acceptable, if: -> { (last_name_changed? || first_name_changed?) && (persisted? || !imported?) }
  def name_is_acceptable
    [:first_name, :last_name].each do |attr|
      value = self.send(attr)
      next if value.blank? || value =~ NAME_FORMAT

      errors.add attr, I18n.t(:resident_name_invalid, scope: 'errors.messages')
    end
  end
```

#### app/view/resident/_update.html.erb

```
<%= text_field_tag 'resident[last_name]', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Last Name', required: true, maxlength: 50, pattern: '^(?!.*\.\S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ \',.-]+$', oninvalid: "setCustomValidity('Contains unsupported characters.')", oninput: "setCustomValidity('')" %>
```

#### error on clientside

```
Pattern attribute value (?-mix:^(?!.*\.\S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ \',.-]+$) is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?-mix:^(?!.*\.\S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ \',.-]+$)/: Invalid group
```

Comment: That's an ambitious regular expression but don't forget names like Ragnheiður and Altuğ exist. This is an incomplete set of Latin letters with accents and may prove to be a frustrating impediment to your users.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure about your codes. It might be missing flags. Your expression seems to be working fine:

```
/^(?!.*\.\S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ \',.-]+$/m
```

#### Ruby Test

```
re = /^(?!.*\.\S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ \',.-]+$/m
str = 'abcàâä'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

#### RegEx

You can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UX8nim/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /^(?!.*\.\S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ \',.-]+$/gm;
const str = `abcàâä`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to modify the Resident model with a new constant and work from there.

#### resident.rb

```
JS_NAME_FORMAT = '^(?!.*\.\S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ \',.-]+$'
NAME_FORMAT = /#{JS_NAME_FORMAT}/
```

#### _update.html.erb

```
<%= text_field_tag 'resident[last_name]', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Last Name', required: true, maxlength: 50, pattern: Resident::JS_NAME_FORMAT, oninvalid: "setCustomValidity('Contains unsupported characters.')", oninput: "setCustomValidity('')" %>
```

Doing this I still only define express in a single spot, which my primary goal.

Comment: You might be better off using [`\p{...}`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) instead of that explicit list of accented characters. Or just drop the restriction because any restriction will be broken in one way or another. Also [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Also also, you almost always want `\A` and `\z` rather than `^` and `$` in Ruby. Of course, you won't get very far getting one non-trivial regex to work in regex engines.

Comment: @muistooshort So this would be the new pattern? `\A(?!.*\.\S)[\p{L} \',.-]+\z`

Comment: If so I'm getting this error `Invalid regular expression: /\A(?!.*\.\S)[\p{L} ',.-]+\z/: Invalid escape` in the browser

Comment: `\p{L}` looks like a good start, might want to include `\p{P}` rather than just those four punctuations (there are names like `D’arcy` and they may not want to spell it `D'arcy`l). JavaScript wants you to use the `u` modifier so you'd say `/.../u`. And down the rabbit hole we go into a nightmare of special cases and frustration. If this isn't a hard external requirement then maybe usernames should just be arbitrary strings of characters (with Unicode normalization of some sort of course). This is a surprisingly difficult topic. Also, I don't think JavaScript understands `\A` and `\z`.